# play music stream with gstreamer-sharp

Tags: mono, gstreamer

I am looking fo an example showing me how to play an mp3 stream from a URL.
I am trying to build a comand line client for apache using mono with gstreamer.
So far I haven't found any clue how to use gstreamer sharp - does anybody have any experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Banshee source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/tree/src/Backends/Banshee.GStreamerSharp/Banshee.GStreamerSharp), we have a GStreamerSharp backend.

Comment: I ran over the code and have to say that it is quite complex. Can you point out which file is interesting in particular? I am looking for something like a hello workd for gstreamer-sharp?

Comment: I guess most important things are in PlayerEngine.cs file, setting the URI of the resource ( playbin.Uri = uri.AbsoluteUri; ) and then setting the playbin state ( playbin.SetState (Gst.State.Playing); )